# Que criptografia é essa?

Tags: php, criptografia

Me deparei com esse tipo: `$2a$08$Cf1f11ePArKlBJomM0F6a.xzfpEexCPc/xm.u/Tv/pK6K..cagbv.` de criptografia na base de dados de um cliente porem não conheço, alguém sabe do que se trata?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Se o que procura é o protocolo específico, `2a` é o prefixo do `CRYPT_BLOWFISH`. Aqui tem mais detalhes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C)

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que isso se trata da bcrypt.
Por algum acaso isso está na coluna de senhas?

As funções hash tradicionais MD5, sha1, ... não garantem que o resultado estejam realmente seguros, ou seja, a partir do valor guardado no BD que não tenha como advinhar qual o seu valor original. Isso se dá pelo fato de as senhas possuirem poucas informações, normalmente 6 caracteres.

Para corrigir isso funções hash como bcrypt foram criadas, onde é adicionado um fator de aleatoriedade e seu nível de dificuldade (grosseiramente é quantidade de iterações). Para mais informações: [Criptografando senhas no PHP usando bcrypt (Blowfish)](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/criptografando-senhas-no-php-usando-bcrypt-blowfish) (Recomendo muito a leitura).

Para a manipulação do resultado e posterior verificação de senhas é armazenada a informação do método utilizado e qual o seu custo (dificuldade). No seu caso

Método: $a2 -> bcrypt

Custo: $08 -> dificuldade 8

O que sobra é o resultado da função hash.

Comment: Eu consigo quebrar esse tipo de criptografia?

Comment: Sim, é possível de ser quebrada assim como qualquer outra função hash. O que irá garantir que está seguro é o custo envolvido para descobri o valor inicial. 
A parte interessante do bcrypt é que ele possui um custo variável, ou seja, conforme os computadores vão ficando mais potentes basta aumentar o custo (dificuldade) da hash. Contudo esse valor não pode ser alto pois o tempo para calcular essa hash aumenta consideravelmente. 
Se não me engano, o valor atual com um bom custo-benefício (segurança x tempo de processamento) está em 10, mas seria bom verificar essa informação.